# Oracle Sql Query : dba_segments + dba_objects

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I wish to modify this sql to add the max(created) and max(last_ddl_time) from dba_objects.
How do I do that ? Thank you.

```
select owner, segment_name, sum(bytes) sb 
from dba_segments 
where tablespace_name = 'USERS' 
group by owner, segment_name order by sb desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
select ds.owner,ds.segment_name,sum(ds.bytes) sb, 
max(do.created) mc, max(do.last_ddl_time) md
from dba_segments ds join dba_objects do 
  on (ds.owner=do.owner and ds.segment_name=do.object_name)
where tablespace_name = 'USERS'
group by ds.owner, ds.segment_name
order by sb desc;
```

If this makes sense is another matter :-)

Comment: Thank you. That worked.